# Iterative decompose-as-sum-of-squares in Racket

Tags: racket

I already tried this problem multiple times but can't seen to get it right. I want to write an iterative procedure decompose-as-sum-of-squares which inputs a positive integer n and outputs the first integer p such that `p^2 + q^2 = n`, where `q^2 = (n - p^2)`, and neither `p` nor `n - p^2` is 1. If such p does not exist, the function should return n. 
A sample output is `(dss 65)`returns 4.

This is my code so far.

```
(define (dss n)
  (define (sum-of-squares n)
    (if (zero? n) 0
        (cons (expt n 2)
              (sum-of-squares (- n 1)))))
  (sum-of-squares 1))
```

The output I get is

```
(dss 65)    ; (1 . 0)
```

Which is clearly wrong. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists have nothing to do with this problem, the solution follows from the definition: you have to test all `p` values starting from `2` and see if we can find an integer `q` greater than `1` that satisfies the formula `p^2 + q^2 = n`. Something like this:

```
(define (dss n)
  (define (sum-of-squares p)
    (cond ((>= p n) n)
          ((let ((q (sqrt (- n (sqr p)))))
             (and (integer? q) (not (= q 1))))
           p)
          (else (sum-of-squares (add1 p)))))
  (sum-of-squares 2))

(dss 65)
=> 4
```

Comment: Do you mean sqrt for this part: (sqr p). Also when I test (dss 65) the result is 65 not 4.

Comment: No, I meant `sqr` - which is the `square` procedure built into racket: `(lambda (x) (* x x))`. Did you change anything? because it works on my machine...

Comment: There's an error when I use sqr: sqr: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier. Do I have to write a square procedure then?

Comment: It's because of the language you're using. Then define it, it's trivial: `(define (sqr x) (* x x))`